# XHR request changes response based on file extension

Tags: javascript, nginx

I have a binary file that contains an Uint8 array *[0,1,2,3,4,5]*.

If I name it **test.txt** and load it everything is fine. However if I change its extension name to **test.bpg** the loaded data is [1,4].

What could make this happen? It doesn't happen when I run the file on local host (note only firefox will let me do this because of cross origin security).

However when I upload it to the server the strange responses start happening. I never configured the server to do anything special with either .txt files or .bpg files. It's just a standard nginx install.

In case you want to see some code I am retrieving that file like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.open("GET", 'test.txt', true);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
request.onload = (function(event) {
    var data = request.response;
    var array = new Uint8Array(data);
    console.log(array);
});
request.send(null)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe it’s a cached response? What does `curl -v http://…/test.bpg` show?

Comment: @Ryan, That's a good idea to test it with curl. It's strange because the curl response shows the same content length for both files. However I don't see how it could be cached, as I've tried changing the directories name several times and rerunning the tests with the same results. Unless is it possible for a cache to exist between directories? Or could nginx have some sort of internal cache?

Comment: Can you edit the full output for each of the `curl -v`s into your question?